# Modify ContactId on an Opportunity via API

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, contact, python

#### Question

Is it possible to modify `ContactId` field on an Opportunity? I get a field security error, but I did not find an option to change the security level of the field.

#### Motivation

I have records with missing `ContactId` that I want to fill in.

#### Example Python Code

```python
from simple_salesforce import SalesForce

sf = Salesforce(username=SALESFORCE_EMAIL, password=SALESFORCE_PASSWORD, security_token=SALESFORCE_TOKEN)

opportunity_id = '0067Q00000Bw2rgQAB'
new_contact_id = '0037Q00000LOEvxQAH'
sf.Opportunity.update(opportunity_id, data={'ContactId': new_contact_id})
```

#### Error

> 'Unable to create/update fields: ContactId. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm), the `ContactId` field is read-only.

> Read-only field that is derived from the opportunity contact role,
> which is created at the same time the opportunity is created. This
> field can only be populated when it’s created, and can’t be updated.
> To update the value in this field, change the IsPrimary flag on the
> OpportunityContactRole associated with this opportunity. Available in
> API version 46.0 and later.

Comment: "change the IsPrimary flag on the OpportunityContactRole associated"
I think that solves that. Thank you!